# the '%' symbol is shown as '?' in ms-outlook on passing htmltext from flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, outlook

I am trying to pass htmltext which contains '%' symbol as a deafult template to ms-outlook.
The problem is that '%' symbol gets conveted to '?' in ms-outlook.

what should i do to get '%' symbol instead of '?'.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the % sign with its url encoded equivalent %25 . I assume you're opening a mailto: link with the body appended as a url parameter, which is where outlook gets confused with the encoding.